# Creating an index with foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am using ef core 2.1 preview 2. I need to create a composite index in an mssql database on a table involving a foreign key. The following is semantically what I am after however the syntax is invalid:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
        .HasIndex(p => new { p.Baz.Id, p.Foo, p.Bar })
        .IsUnique();
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927276/ef-core-navigational-property-in-index/47930643#47930643

Comment: Ugh, I hit F12 to see the source so I could check the overloads and the file that comes up when you have invoked the overload that takes an expression does not contain the overload that accepts an array (there is only one signature). Using proper intellisense reveals the other... Thank you very much!